# Django, Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.) How to catch when a form submitted and redirect to GET

Tags: django, redirect, django-csrf

How do you control over CSRF token error when a client submits the form with POST and if CSRF token error occurs, I'd like to redirect the client to def get which has a form.

I found only CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW can be set to an error page but there is nothing I can control over redirection for CSRF error.

When the error occurs, Django make an internal server error.

So I cannot catch the error in the view.